# Como mudar a classe de uma variável dentro de uma tabela/ data frame/ tibble?

Tags: r, data.frame, dplyr

Tenho uma tabela chamada `tab01` com as seguintes variáveis (colunas) e suas respectivas classes entre parênteses: `uf` (character), `regiao` (character), `ano` (double) e `pop` (double).

Quero, dentro da tabela:
1) transformar a variável regiao para a classe fator, e
2) informar ao R que a variável ano corresponde a uma "data"

Então, como faço isso usando o base R? E usando o ecossistema tidyverse?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

primeiro seria bom se você expusesse seus dados ou uma parte deles para tornar o problema reproduzível. Mas, aqui pegando um caso genérico.

```
library(dplyr)

tibble(uf=c("AM", "RJ", "SC"),
       regiao=c("norte", "sudeste", "sul"),
       ano=c(1989, 1987, 1986),
       pop=runif(3)) %>% 
       print() %>% 
       {.} -> dt

#     uf  regiao   ano        pop
#  <chr>   <chr> <dbl>      <dbl>
#1    AM   norte  1989 0.05092618
#2    RJ sudeste  1987 0.54035176
#3    SC     sul  1986 0.54615493
```

Para alterar a tipagem das variáveis é só aplicar a função `mutate` do pacote `dplyr`. Na parte da data deve-se estabelecer um dia e um mês para usar o tipo **date**, no exemplo abaixo usei o dia primeiro de janeiro, que será aplicado a todas as linhas.

```
dt %>% 
        mutate(regiao=as.factor(regiao)) %>% 
        mutate(ano=as.Date(ISOdate(ano, 1, 1)))

#     uf  regiao        ano        pop
#  <chr>  <fctr>     <date>      <dbl>
#1    AM   norte 1989-01-01 0.05092618
#2    RJ sudeste 1987-01-01 0.54035176
#3    SC     sul 1986-01-01 0.54615493
```

O que você poderia fazer diferente aqui seria usar um único `mutate` para alterar ambas colunas, como:

```
dt %>% 
        mutate(regiao=as.factor(regiao),
               ano=as.Date(ISOdate(ano, 1, 1)))
```

Comment: Obrigado, Rafael!  
Para complementar, a partir da sua resposta percebi que para fazer a mesma coisa sem usar o pipe, bastava colocar o dt dentro do mutate: 

mutate(dt, regiao = as.factor(regiao), ano = as.Date(ISOdate(ano, 1, 1)))

Comment: @Enoch, tenha em mente que `dt %>% mutate(...)` é equivalente à `mutate(dt, ...)`